# Problemas con las app de phonegap

Tags: android, phonegap

Bien, esta no es una duda de programación pero si alguien pudiera ayudarme:

Descargué la aplicación de escritorio de **Phonegap**, a partir de ella cree un proyecto, la cual lo compilo y me da la siguiente dirección: `192.168.3.125.3000`.

Ahora intentando acceder desde mi celular utilizando la app de Phonegap no he podido, ya que ingreso la dirección y solo se queda en

> "DOWNLOADING..." "TAP TO CANCEL"

y no pasa a mas, en cambio lo pruebo en otro celular y se visualiza perfectamente, estoy conectado a la misma red de wi-fi, mi celular es un LG Max con Android 5.0 , ya restauré mi celular pero sigue sin funcionar.

¿Qué creen que pueda ser?.

Comment: La dirección debes colocar 192.168.3.125:3000 seguro es por eso que no lo visualizas

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero creeme que si he puesto la dirección correctamente... :/

Comment: Después de desactivar el firewall de win 10 la app sigue sin poder conectarse

Comment: a mi me pasaba lo mismo, no conecta en el móvil; pero salia otra ip , probe con esa y conecto

Answer (score 0):

Averigua la IP de tu telefono movil.
En tu PC pulsa los botones (windows+r), y escribe en el dialogo que te aparezca "cmd".

En el escribe el comando "ping (ip de tu telefono)".

De esta manera comprobarás si se logran ver y se encuentran en la misma red.
Si funciona respondeme.